# How do you use JAXB to unmarshall an empty tag as tag element's name instead of its value of empty string?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an input XML file which uses empty tag to represent valid data. I cannot change this. The item material can be either "metal" or "plastic" as specified by empty tags `<metal/>` and `<plastic/>`. The problem with JAXB is that it unmarshalls empty tags to empty strings. How can I use JAXB be so that I could extract `<metal/>` and `<plastic/>` as their xml tag names, strings `"metal"` and `"plastic"` rather than their empty values? If there is no way to do it using JAXB, what parser should I use?

XML Input File

```
<items>
   <item>
      <id>item 1<id>
      <material>
          <metal/>
      </material>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>item 2<id>
      <material>
          <plastic/>
      </material>
   </item>
</items>
```

Java bean class for corresponding Java object.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "items")
public class Items{
    private List<Item> items;


    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public void setItes(List<Item> items) {
        this.items= items;
    }

    public static class Item{

        private String        id;
        private String        material;



        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "id")
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getMaterial() {
                return material;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public void setMaterial(String material) {
                this.material = material;
        }
```

Controller class

```
public class ItemParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //  System.out.println("Hello World!");


        try {

            File file = new File("I:\\items.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( Items.class );

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Items items = (Items) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( file );


          } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define another class named Material and inside that class need to define metal and plastic

Comment: I tried that before posting a question, but the approach wouldn't work because in this case JAXB treats <plastic/> and <metal/> as empty tags. As a result, it sets the field of the the Java class to an empty string.  I tried to use a location listener, but that approach didn't work either. I ended up using a DOM parser which allowed me to parse out the name of an empty tag.